# externalinterface firefox bug

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, flex4, externalinterface

I cannot get ANY web-based examples of ExternalInferface to work in Firefox. Is there a bug with my player or Firebug? Take in mind i said NO examples work in FireFox 13.0.1 with FlashPlayer 11.3 on my Windows7 box or on my laptop (same browser specs).

1. Adobe ExternalInterface examples do not work.
2. swfobject google.code examples do not work: http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_com.html.
3. ExternalInterface | Flex Examples do not work: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/04/11/getting-javascript-variables-into-your-flex-applications-using-the-externalinterface-api/

WTF is going on with Firefox? If none of the web examples work then it must be my browser right or is this a true Firefox bug?

Comment: those examples work on for me using the same os/browser/flashplayer version. do you have javascript enabled in your browser? perhaps there's a security, ad-blocker, or other extension messing you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the examples via localhost or an actual web server, or trying to locally load the html files (without localhost)? ExternalInterface requires a webserver and javascript with AllowScriptAccess enabled. I suspect your problem is most likely with one of those two.

Here is [additional security info](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_6.html) about ExternalInterface.